# Simple Multi Thread code to be clarified

Tags: java, c, multithreading

I've got this little problem on thread.

```
    int x = 0;
    add() {

      x=x+1;
    }
```

If we run this in multiple threads, say 4 threads, is the final value of x=4 at every time or it could be 1,2,3 or 4.

Thanks

PS 
lets say the atomic operations for the adding is like this,

```
LOAD A x
ADD A 1 
LOAD x A
```

Then the final result will be 4. Am I right or what have I get wrong ?

Comment: I suggest you put a language tag to get more attention, event though it seems like a general question.

Comment: are you saying 4 `threads` or 4 `for-loop`  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classical example of data race.

Now, let's take a closer look at what add() does:

```
add()
{
   x = x + 1;
}
```

This translates to:

1. Give me the most recent value of X and store it in my private workspace
2. Add 1 to that value that is stored in my private workspace
3. Copy what I have in my workspace to the memory that I copied from (that is globally accessible).

Now, before we go further in explaining this, you have something called [context switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch), which is the process by which your operating system divides your processor's time among different threads and processes. This process usually gives your threads a finite amount of processor time (on windows it is about 40 milliseconds) and then interrupts that work, copies everything the processor have in its registers (and by thus preserve it's state) and switch to the next task. This is called [Round-robin task scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_scheduling).

You have no control over when you're processing is going to be interrupted and transferred to another thread.

Now imagine you have two threads doing the same:

```
1. Give me the most recent value of X and store it in my private workspace
2. Add 1 to that value that is stored in my private workspace
3. Copy what I have in my workspace to the memory that I copied from (that is globally accessible).
```

and X is equal to 1 before any of them runs.

The first thread might execute the first instruction and store in it's private workspace the value of X that was most recent at the time it was working on - 1. Then a context-switch occurs and the operating system interrupts your threads and gives control to the next task in queue, that happens to be the second thread. The second thread also reads the value of X which is equal to 1.

Thread number two manages to run to completion - it adds 1 to the value it "downloaded" and "uploads" the calculated value.

The operating system forces a context switch again.

Now the first thread continues execution at the point where it was interrupted. It will still think that the most recent value is 1, it will increment that value by one and save the result of it's computation to that memory area. And this is how data races occur. You expect the final result to be 3 but it is 2.

There are many ways to avoid this problem such as [locks/mutexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_%28computer_science%29), [compare and swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare_and_swap) or [atomic operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_operations).

Comment: I would only comment that this discusses implementation details. However, it is better to focus on the guarantees provided (and, especially, **not** provided) by the Java Language Specification. You could run Java on a completely different architecture where most of these points would be invalidated.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is broken at two levels:

1. No `happens-before` relationship imposed between actions of threads;
2. Atomicity of get-and-increment not enforced.

To solve 1. you can add the `volatile` modifier. This will still leave the operation non-atomic. To ensure atomicity, you would use (preferably) an `AtomicInteger` or `synchronized` (involves locking, not preferred).

As it stands, the result can be **any number from 0 to 4** if read from a thread that was not involved in incrementing.

Answer (score 2):

Multi-thread applications are concurrent (this is the whole point).

```
t1: LOAD A1 x
t2: LOAD A2 x
t3: LOAD A3 x
t4: LOAD A4 x
t1: ADD A1 1 
t2: ADD A2 1 
t3: ADD A3 1 
t4: ADD A4 1 
t1: STORE x A1
t2: STORE x A2
t3: STORE x A3
t4: STORE x A4
```

A1, A2, A3, A4 are local registers.

The result is `1`, but it could be `2`, `3` or `4`. If you have another thread it could see the old value due to visability issues and see `0`